# SSRS 2005: Return NULL Values in Report with Parameter

Tags: t-sql, reportingservices-2005

I have a parameter called @vConsultant, which I use in a stored procedure as well as in an SSRS report.  The parameter is a drop-down menu populated by this query:

```
select distinct c.nameConsultant
from dataTable d

left join consultants c on d.nameConsultant= d.recID
```

"dataTable" is my main data table that stores the ID of the consultant.  Consultants is the table that stores the names.

The issue:  In dataTable, the consultant is an optional field.  And, in the reporting, my users want to see not only those consultants they select in the SSRS drop-down, but also the NULL values (where the user didn't specify a consultant).  However, the "NULL" doesn't show up as a value in the drop-down menu in SSRS.

In the stored proc, when I want to return NULLS, I do it with my where clause.  So...my proc is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spReportProc] 

@vConsultant varchar(max) 

AS


BEGIN
    --Get comma-delimited list of consultants to allow SSRS multi-value select.
    Select @vConsultant = ',' + @vConsultant + ','

    create table #Consultant
        (
            nameConsultant varchar(1000)
        )
    Insert Into #Consultant 
    Select  nameConsultant
    From consultants
    Where @vConsultant Like  '%,' + nameConsultant ',%'
    And classification = 'Implementation Consultant'
    Group By nameConsultant


    Select * From dataTable d

    left join consultants c on d.nameConsultant= d.recID


    Where 
    @vConsultant Is NULL Or @vConsultant Like '%,' + i.firstName + ' ' + i.lastName + ',%') 
END
```

But specifying NULL in this manner doesn't get noticed in SSRS.  Is there a way to allow NULL values in SSRS without actually specifying a NULL as part of the SSRS drop-down?  I have tried selecting the "Allow Null" and "Allow Blank" check boxes in SSRS, but that isn't working either.

Let me know if more clarification is needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To workaround the issue with nulls in multi-value drop-downs, I include an option called "-- Optional --", and then use that in the where clause instead of checking for a null.

So your first query becomes (change to inner join to ensure no nulls):

```
select '-- Optional --'
union
select distinct c.nameConsultant
from dataTable d

inner join consultants c on d.nameConsultant= d.recID
```

And replace the where clause in your procedure with:

```
Where 
    @vConsultant != '-- Optional --' Or @vConsultant Like '%,' + i.firstName + ' ' + i.lastName + ',%')
```

Comment: I accepted this, but I did make a modification - so, not sure if this is the right place to put this, but...

I did end up creating a new optional field in the drop-down using your union, but I did this as well:

    Declare @vAllowBlanks
    select @vAllowBlanks= IsNull(Charindex(',(Optional),',@vConsultant),0)
    
    Then in the where clause:
    ( (@vConsultantLike '%,' + i.firstName + ' ' + i.lastName + ',%') Or (@vConsultant= 1 And i.firstName + ' ' + i.lastName Is Null) )

Answer (score 0):

Click the parameter property of vConsultant parameter and check 'Allow null value' property and click ok.It will display a check box in the report parameter to select whether the value is null or selected value.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that because my drop-down is a "multi-value" property, and SSRS won't let you select both check boxes (or, it won't let me at least...)